# Htaccess rule to move entire site into a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two folders in `httpdocs`

```
site_v1
site_v2
```

I would like to redirect the entire domain to site_v2 but also to keep reference to this

so this would work

```
www.example.com -> gets into site_v2
www.example.com/site_v1/ -> gets into site_v1
www.example.com/site_v2/ -> gets into site_v2
```

How would be the htaccess directives for this kind of redirect?

Comment: RewriteRule ^site_v1/ site_v2
  -- I'm writing a comment because I can't test it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^(site_v1|site_v2)($|/)
RewriteRule .* site_v2/$0 [L]
```